# How to find the user name who merged the pr to the base branch from the octokit library

Tags: octokit-js

Can anyone tell me that how to fetch the user name who merged the pr by the octokit.request api call.

I can fetch all the prs from octokit.request method with the query parameter state=all value. It is returning the array having all PRs (open and closed all). We can see that PRs with merged_at value is not equal to null are the pr which are merged.
Now how to find the user name who merged this pr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my question.
These are the steps.

1. Get the merged PR by retrieving closed PRs and check for merged_at!=null.
2. Get the user login from response of step 1, i.e. by mergedPRs.user.login.
3. Get All commits of the main branch.
4. Filter and take those commits only whose `commit.commit.commiter.name==='GitHub`'. this will filter and take those commit only by which the PR is merged.
5. now If step2===step4 then you got the answer. i.e. `mergedPRs.user.login === filteredCommit.commit.author.login`.
   You got the answer, it will tell you the pr is created and merged by same person or not.

- Here is the code for the same.

```
     const allCommits : Array<any> = await getAllCommits(data);    
     const mergedPRs : Array<any> = await getMergedPRs(data);
     const MergeCommitsUserDetailsWithsha : Array<UserWithCommitSha> = []
     allCommits.forEach(commit => {
         if(commit.commit.committer.name==="GitHub"){
             let objectToPush : UserWithCommitSha = {username:commit.author.login, commitsha:commit.sha};
             MergeCommitsUserDetailsWithsha.push(objectToPush);
            }
         });
     const selfMergedPRs : Array<any> = mergedPRs.filter(pr=>{
         return MergeCommitsUserDetailsWithsha.some(element => element.username===pr.user.login && element.commitsha===pr.merge_commit_sha);
     });
    
     let result : Array<SelfMergedPRs>=[];
     selfMergedPRs.forEach(pr => {
            result.push({url:pr.html_url, userName:pr.user.login, commit:pr.merge_commit_sha, headBranch:pr.head.ref, baseBranch:pr.base.ref})
     });
        
     return result;
```

- Here the getAllCommits function is returning all commits of the default branch of the given repository.
- getMergedPRs returns the PRs which are closed by merging it.
- In some method we are filtering those PRs in which the author's login who created the PRs is same as the merge commit's author's login who merged the PR.